# How to fix my LED array's from snaking and instead make them all start from the next number from the right side

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

Essentially I am trying to convey an array onto an array of LEDs for tetris (A project for my class).  The main problem with this is that the LED array in which I'm trying to display onto is Snaking due to the connections on the board going from right to left and then left to right.

I'm currently working with a 32 x 8 [array of LEDs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DC0IPVU).  So when I light up Leds[board[0][7]] = CRGB::White that lights up the top left of the board.  But Leds[board[1][0]] = CRGB::White lights up the second light right underneath it.  Instead I want it to start from the right side like the one above it is.  This makes it really tough to code a 2x2 square onto these lights since they always turn out inverted onto the LED array due to this snaking.

I.e. { 1, 1, 0, 0 } will display as { 0, 0, 1, 1 } on the row below.

I just need it to display the same on the row below so I can just go down the arrays.
I.e. board[x - 1][y];

Sorry if this is a little confusing but this is the best way I can explain it.  If more clarification is needed, please let me know.

I have mainly coded in Java and this is my first time using arduino.  So I don't know if there is a difference between arduino's arrays and java's.

So far, I've tried somewhat counter snaking the array of LEDs, but it always shifts one LED row over to the right when its should be directly underneath the other LEDs.  That code will be below.

```
int setBoard = 0;
int board[32][8];

//trying to make tetris, so i'm starting with the oPiece.
int oPiece[2][2] = {
  { 1, 1 },
  { 1, 1 }  
};


//This is my setup for the board.  In here I am trying to make every other row 
go from right to left instead of left to right in which it normally does.
void setup() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      //This outputs correctly.
      if(i % 2 == 0) {        
        for(int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
          board[i][z] = setBoard;
          setBoard++;
        }
      }
      //This doesn't output correctly.  Shifts all LEDs on every one of these 
      //rows over to the right by one.  
      if(i % 2 != 0) {
        setBoard+= 8;

        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
          board[i][y] = setBoard;
          setBoard--;
        }
        setBoard+= 8;
      }

   }
}

//displays the piece onto the 2d array by a certain y offset.
void showPiece() {
  for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      if(oPiece[x][y] == 1) {
        leds[board[x][y + 6]] = CHSV(255, 75, 75);
      }        
    }
  }
  FastLED.show();
}

void loop() {
  showPiece();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `setup` doesn't quite get the maths right for generating the `setBoard` variable.

If I print the first three rows of `board`, I get:

```
0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
16      15      14      13      12      11      10      9
16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23
```

So `8` is missing and `16` is repeated.

Changing the code for odd-numbered rows:

```
if(i % 2 != 0)
{
    setBoard += 7;

    for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        board[i][y] = setBoard;
        setBoard--;
    }
    setBoard += 9;
}
```

gives the correct output:

```
0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
15      14      13      12      11      10      9       8
16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23
```